# How to add multiple class file in one XAML file in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am designing a **UI Library** and  I want to add **two** `C# file` to a `XAML` file so that in one file I can  define only event Handler to be used in that Xaml file and in another file i can define some other UI related Style for controls. And i want my  `xaml` file to have access to my both `C#` file class directly.

I am doing something like this using `x:Class`:

For example:

I want to add a `MainWindow.cs` file to my XAML file:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="TemplateLibrary.MainWindow">
```

But unfortunately XAML supports for only one class to get added to my XAML. Is there some way to add multiple C# file to a XAML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your case you need to look in the direction of `MVVM`, because the further complication of the project will cause some difficulties. You can create multiple `ViewModel's` for a one `View`. In the role of `View` may suit:

- UserControl
- DataTemplate

In the case of `UserControl` this class can be partial, which will complement the other class. In the case of `DataTemplate` can dynamically change the content depending on `View` type.

In addition, all styles of Control's must be contained in `ResourceDictionary` and merged into the *`App.xaml`* file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the MainWindow code behind is already a partial class file, and therefore we could choose to place some members into additional cs files using the same partial class in the same namespace.

```
namespace TemplateLibrary
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ...
```

The same applies when making a UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

More basic is "How to bind an XAML visual object to code".  Ranny Meier's suggestion on declaring my class on it's page as a 'partial class' coupled with (can't find him again) suggestion of using a redirection on the mainwindow page actually works fine - all in the same name space of course.

> ### xaml

```
    <Button x:Name="Pnl_Btn_EditPaste" Click="Do_Btn_EditPaste_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="2" Margin="-67,18,0,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="36" Height="30" RenderTransformOrigin="1.976,-0.568">
         <Button.OpacityMask>
             <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/BnFace_paste.png"/>
         </Button.OpacityMask>
         <Button.Background>
             <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/BnFace_paste.png"/>
         </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

It's the "Click=" portion, or binding, on the Button opening statement we're interested in . . .

> ### mainwindow c#

```
   namespace WpfAppFoolAround
   {
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // -- Edit Controls ---------------------------------------------------------

        private void Do_Btn_EditPaste_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContextControls.Btn_EditPaste(sender, e);
        }
     }
   }
```

The shim on mainwindow to redirect us to the class method . . .

> ### the class on a different page

```
    namespace WpfAppFoolAround
    {
        public partial class ContextControls
        {

           // -- Edit Controls ---------------------------------------------------

            internal static void Btn_EditPaste(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("PASTE Editing Button Clicked.");
            }
        }
    }
```

And the actual method located in the class on the odd project page we added.